# Скрыть блоки, если их более заданного количества при вложенности

Tags: javascript

Есть аккордеоны, внутри которых тоже аккордеоны (на данный момент их может быть более трех). Так вот, если количество вложений (других аккордеонов) в аккордеоне верхнего уровня превышает, к примеру, три штуки - их мы скрываем. Проблема в том, что никак не могу понять как проверять количество вложений внутри других вложений. Как видно **Level 2** скрывает блоки правильно, но в **Level 1** при более глубокой вложенности **Sub Level 1 Option 1** имеет три скрытых элемента, вместо двух. **Есть идеи как решить?**
[На codepen'e.](https://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/BdvoGr)
Сам код ниже:

```js
console.clear();

let expands = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper > .expand');

expands.forEach(expand => {
 let title = expand.querySelectorAll('.title');
 let expandAsExpand = expand.querySelectorAll('.expand');
 
 Array.from(expandAsExpand).filter((item, index) => {
  if(index > 2) {
   item.style.display = 'none';
  }
 })
 title.forEach(title_item => {
  title_item.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
   target.parentElement.classList.toggle('active')
  }) 
 }) 
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 414px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.expand.active > .title {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.expand.active > .content {
  height: 100%;
}
.expand .title {
  margin: 0 0 .5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
.expand .title:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.expand .expand {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
.expand .content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="expand test">
  <div class="title">Level 1</div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 1</div>
    <div class="content">
     <div class="expand">
      <div class="title">Sub Level 2 Option 1</div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="expand">
      <div class="title">Sub Level 2 Option 2</div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="expand">
      <div class="title">Sub Level 2 Option 3</div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="expand">
      <div class="title">Sub Level 2 Option 4</div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="expand">
      <div class="title">Sub Level 2 Option 5</div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>   
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="expand test">
  <div class="title">Level 2</div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 1</div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 2</div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 3</div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 4</div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 5</div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выборка по css селектору `:nth-child(n+3)` думаю поможет

```js
console.clear();

let expands = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper > .expand');

expands.forEach(expand => {
 let title = expand.querySelectorAll('.title');
 let expandAsExpand = expand.querySelectorAll(':nth-child(n+3)');
  
  for(let item of expandAsExpand) {
    item.style.display = 'none';
  }
 title.forEach(title_item => {
  title_item.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
   target.parentElement.classList.toggle('active')
  }) 
 }) 
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 414px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.expand.active > .title {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.expand.active > .content {
  height: 100%;
}
.expand .title {
  margin: 0 0 .5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
.expand .title:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.expand .expand {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
.expand .content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="expand test">
  <div class="title">Level 1</div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 1</div>
    <div class="content">
     <div class="expand">
      <div class="title">Sub Level 2 Option 1</div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="expand">
      <div class="title">Sub Level 2 Option 2</div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="expand">
      <div class="title">Sub Level 2 Option 3</div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="expand">
      <div class="title">Sub Level 2 Option 4</div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="expand">
      <div class="title">Sub Level 2 Option 5</div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>   
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="expand test">
  <div class="title">Level 2</div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 1</div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 2</div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 3</div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 4</div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="expand">
    <div class="title">Sub Level 1 Option 5</div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Просто и гениально! Благодарю!